# Conditionally coloring the cells' background

Tags: list-manipulation

In a certain way, it's certainly a duplicate question. But I did not find the original.

I have adapted an old code to obtain the following nice presentation of the matrix

```
mtc = {{0, 2784, 2788, 2720, 2766}, {3034, 0, 2780, 2748, 2637}, {3030, 
  3038, 0, 2932, 3028}, {3098, 3070, 2886, 0, 2795}, {3052, 3181, 
  2790, 3023, 0}}
```

Here is the code:

```
 Grid[Join[{Join[{"(x,y)"}, l]}, Flatten /@ Transpose[{l, mtc}]], 
 Alignment -> Center, 
 Background -> {{1 -> LightGray}, {1 -> LightGray}, {1, 1} -> None}, 
 Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}}, 
 ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16], Frame -> True, 
 Spacings -> {1.5, 1.5}]
```

But now I would like that, if a number say $x[i, j]$ is greater than a number $x[j, i]$, the backgroud be lightreded, and, lightblued in the contrary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just another way:

```
With[{sgn = Sign[mtc - Transpose[mtc]]},
 Grid[mtc, 
  Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
    Thread[Position[sgn, 1] -> LightRed]~Join~
     Thread[Position[sgn, -1] -> LightBlue]}, Frame -> All]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The OP didn't specify what `l` is, so:

```
mtc = {{0, 2784, 2788, 2720, 2766}, {3034, 0, 2780, 2748, 
    2637}, {3030, 3038, 0, 2932, 3028}, {3098, 3070, 2886, 0, 
    2795}, {3052, 3181, 2790, 3023, 0}};
l = CharacterRange["a", "e"];
```

Then, it's not clear what should happen with the diagonal elements, so:

```
back = Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[Which[mtc[[i, j]] > mtc[[j, i]], {i + 1, j + 1} -> LightRed, 
    mtc[[i, j]] < mtc[[j, i]], {i + 1, j + 1} -> LightGreen, 
    i == j, {i + 1, j + 1} -> None], {i, Length@mtc}, {j, 
    Length@mtc[[1]]}]
```

and

```
plot = Grid[
  Join[{Join[{"(x,y)"}, l]}, Flatten /@ Transpose[{l, mtc}]], 
  Alignment -> Center, 
  Background -> {{1 -> LightGray}, {1 -> LightGray}, {{1, 1} -> None}~
     Join~back}, Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}}, 
  ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16], Frame -> True, 
  Spacings -> {1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

---

If the diagonal is to be in either of the classes, an `If` statement is a bit shorter:

```
back = Flatten[#, 1] &@
  Table[If[mtc[[i, j]] > mtc[[j, i]], {i + 1, j + 1} -> 
     LightRed, {i + 1, j + 1} -> LightGreen], {i, Length@mtc}, {j, 
    Length@mtc[[1]]}]
```

Then

[image]

Comment: Super Thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

Here is a generic approach to position based styling.  [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) is a natural tool to use in conjunction with a styling function.

```
Module[
 {l = Range@Length@mtc,    (* labels *)
  bg},                     (* background function *)
 bg[xy_, pos_] := With[{yx = Extract[mtc, Reverse@pos]},
   Switch[Sign[xy - yx]    (* similar condition as @udpdqn *)
    , -1, LightBlue
    , 1, LightRed
    , _, None]
   ];
 Grid[
  Join[{Join[{"(x,y)"}, l]}, Flatten /@ Transpose[{l, mtc}]],
  Background -> {LightGray, LightGray,
    Join[
     {{1, 1} -> None}, Flatten@MapIndexed[1 + #2 -> bg[##] &, mtc, {2}]
     ]},
  Frame -> All]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It might also be more convenient in some cases to precompute a matrix that indicates the styling, as @udpdqn did with `sgn`.  Here is that idea adapted to the `MapIndexed` approach above:

```
Module[
 {condition = Sign[mtc - Transpose[mtc]], (* conditions for background (= udpdqn's sgn) *)
  l = Range@Length@mtc,                   (* labels *)
  bg},                                    (* background function *)
 bg[-1, pos_] := LightBlue;
 bg[1, pos_] := LightRed;
 bg[_, _] := None;
 Grid[
  Join[{Join[{"(x,y)"}, l]}, Flatten /@ Transpose[{l, mtc}]],
  Background -> {LightGray, 
    LightGray, {{1, 1} -> None}~Join~
     Flatten@MapIndexed[1 + #2 -> bg[##] &, condition, {2}]}, 
  Frame -> All]
 ]
```